# Can't send test email if i use a special email that in my delete contact Associated

Tags: marketing-cloud

I try to send a test email to my email like  test@gmail.com.

[image]

The system like this.

Because I delete a contact In Contact Builder--All Contacts and the delete contact email is the test@gmail.com

[image]

So I can't send a test email or offcial email if i want the  email addr is test@gmail.com.

But if i use other email address like 'test111@gmail.com'

It's works.

So anyone can help me about how to fix it.

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely that you face a problem with contact configuration.

What you have probably done is:
Delete a contact with a contact deletion process of 30 or 14 days, if that period is not over the contact is on status "SUPPRESSED" and you won't be able to reach the email of that contact. Therefore you will have to wait until that contact reaches the end of that suppression time. After that period the contact is really deleted. And you can create that user again.

When you want to change this behaviour of the suppression status you have to go to:

> 1. Contact Builder ->
> 2. Contacts Configuration ->
> 3. Contact Delete ->
> 4. Manage Settings ->
> 5. Set XX "Contacts remain in a suppressed status for XX    days before permanent deletion" to 0

If you are sure that the contacts should immediately be deleted without any chance to get every data back which was connected to them.

Comment: cool ! it's the reason thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which exact email address you are using, but this most likely occurs as 'test' is regarded to be a role-based email address (refer to this [example list](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/role-based-email-addresses/blob/master/index.js)). A Subscriber is, by design, intended to be a 'person', where role-based email addresses are most often not regarded as a person, but typically a distribution list. This isn't just a restriction imposed by Marketing Cloud, but is common for other marketing platforms to suppress role-based email addresses.

You can request support to disable role-based email addresses, and they will provide an interface where you can create records in a whitelist to allow specific role-based email addresses.